# SwaggerUIBundle : Specify base url

Tags: swagger-ui

I need to test a api where :

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| API Url | http://api.mydomain.loc:20109/v1/ |
| API Definition URL | http://api.mydomain.loc:20109/v1/swagger/swagger.json |

The API definition is :

```json
{
  "openapi": "3.0.1",
  "info": {
    "title": "***",
    "description": "***",
    "version": "v1"
  },
  "servers": [
    {
      "url": "/v1/path1/path2"
    }
  ],
  "/ressource1": {
      "get": {
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "Success"
          }
        }
      }
    },
  ...
}
```

I follow this part unpkg in the [documentation](https://swagger.io/docs/open-source-tools/swagger-ui/usage/installation/) to start a local Swagger UI. I create the file "swagger-ui.html" with this content :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <meta
    name="description"
    content="SwaggerIU"
  />
  <title>SwaggerUI</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swagger-ui-dist@4.5.0/swagger-ui.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="swagger-ui"></div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/swagger-ui-dist@4.5.0/swagger-ui-bundle.js" crossorigin></script>
<script>
  window.onload = () => {
    window.ui = SwaggerUIBundle({
      url: 'http://api.mydomain.loc:20109/v1/swagger/swagger.json',
      dom_id: '#swagger-ui',
    });
  };
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I open the page, the API definition is correctly loaded and Swagger UI displayed. But when I try out the endpoint "ressource1", Swagger UI call "http://api.mydomain.loc:20109/v1/path1/path2/ressource1". In my case, I want to call "http://api.mydomain.loc:20109/v1/ressource1".

How override the base path in Swagger UI with unpkg?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's another solution that uses a [plugin](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/blob/master/docs/customization/plugin-api.md) with [`rootInjects`](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/5981). The main idea is the same as in [@vernou's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71207965/113116) - update the OpenAPI definition dynamically.

```html
<!-- index.html -->

<script>
const UrlMutatorPlugin = (system) => ({
  rootInjects: {
    setServer: (server) => {
      const jsonSpec = system.getState().toJSON().spec.json;
      const servers = [{url: server}];
      const newJsonSpec = Object.assign({}, jsonSpec, { servers });

      return system.specActions.updateJsonSpec(newJsonSpec);
    }
  }
});

window.onload = function() {
  const ui = SwaggerUIBundle({
    url: "http://api.mydomain.loc:20109/v1/swagger/swagger.json",
    ...

    // Add UrlMutatorPlugin to the plugins list
    plugins: [
      SwaggerUIBundle.plugins.DownloadUrl,
      UrlMutatorPlugin
    ],

    // This will set appropriate data when Swagger UI is ready
    onComplete: () => {
      window.ui.setServer("http://api.mydomain.loc:20109/v1")
    } 
  });

  window.ui = ui;
};
</script>
```

Comment: I tested, it's work. Don't miss the line `window.ui = ui;`.

Comment: Thank you for this ! Not super straight forward with the swagger documentation. Make sure you have the latest swagger-ui version or it will not work (tested with: swagger-ui-4.14.0)

Answer (score 3):

Swagger UI has the parameter `spec` :

> **spec** : A JavaScript object describing the OpenAPI definition. When used, the url parameter will not be parsed. This is useful for testing manually-generated definitions without hosting them.

The solution is to load manually the api definition, edit the definition and pass the edited definition to Swagger UI.

Example for json OpenApi Specification :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <meta
    name="description"
    content="SwaggerIU"
  />
  <title>SwaggerUI</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swagger-ui-dist@4.5.0/swagger-ui.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="swagger-ui"></div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/swagger-ui-dist@4.5.0/swagger-ui-bundle.js" crossorigin></script>
<script>
  const swaggerUrl = "http://api.mydomain.loc:20109/v1/swagger/swagger.json"
  const apiUrl = "http://api.mydomain.loc:20109/v1/"
  window.onload = () => {
    let swaggerJson = fetch(swaggerUrl).then(r => r.json().then(j => {

      j.servers[0].url = apiUrl;
      window.ui = SwaggerUIBundle({
        spec: j,
        dom_id: '#swagger-ui',
      });
    }));
  };
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Example for yaml OpenApi Specification :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <meta
    name="description"
    content="SwaggerIU"
  />
  <title>SwaggerUI</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swagger-ui-dist@4.15.5/swagger-ui.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="swagger-ui"></div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/swagger-ui-dist@4.15.5/swagger-ui-bundle.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/js-yaml/4.1.0/js-yaml.js" crossorigin></script>
<script>
  const swaggerUrl = "http://api.mydomain.loc:20109/v1/swagger/swagger.yaml"
  const apiUrl = "http://api.mydomain.loc:20109/v1/"
  window.onload = () => {
    let swaggerJson = fetch(swaggerUrl).then(r => r.text().then(t => {
      let j = jsyaml.load(t);
      j.servers[0].url = apiUrl;
      window.ui = SwaggerUIBundle({
        spec: j,
        dom_id: '#swagger-ui',
      });
    }));
  };
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

You can copy this code and just edit the value in `swaggerUrl` and `apiUrl`.

Comment: This works only if you are using the JSON format. If you are using the YAML format, this doesn't work.
So with this solution you always need to use JSON instead of YAML.

Comment: @Helen's solution work with yaml.

Comment: @DavidGausmann - thank for the remark. I updated the answer to manage yaml specification.